# how can i to convert an database object to integer in PHP (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

i have a select that returns a integer value but in the variable it is stored a object that is obvious
i neeed to convert to integer

> $n = DB::select('select top 1 id form tags order by id DESC');

then i need to convert $n to integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This easy to do with ORM, if you have `Tag` model please try,

```
$n = Tag::orderBy('id','desc')->first()->id;
```

Comment: Laravel retursn:                                                                                       
ErrorException
Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object

Answer (score 1):

```
$n = DB::select('select top 1 id form tags order by id DESC')->first();

$id = $n->id;
```

your id now is $id

Comment: `DB::select()` returns an array btw

Comment: laravel returns: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function first() on array